# Courier does not work with courier-ssl installed

Tags: ubuntu, email, ssl, imap

I have been trying to enable SSL on my courier IMAP server running Ubuntu 14.04. I installed `courier-ssl` and `courier-imap-ssl`. Then the server stopped working completely, with an "authentication error" in Rainloop webmail. This happens regardless of whether or not the `courier-imap-ssl` service is started, and is resolved if and only if `courier-ssl` is uninstalled.

What could be the problem here, and how would I go about enabling SSL?

With `courier-ssl` installed and `courier-imap-ssl` running, I get this error if I run `openssl s_client -connect localhost:993`:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1463335379
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

And this error if I run `telnet localhost 993`:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use openssl to connect to SSL services. Plain telnet is not able to communicate with encrypted connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993
```

You can verify service by typing following command after establishing connection:

```
A login MYUSERNAME MYPASSWORD
```

Response should be:

```
A OK LOGIN Ok.
```

One option how to fix incorrect installation is to completely remove the service even with configuration:

```
apt-get remove --pure courier-imap-ssl
```

and reinstall it again.

Problems with SSL are often related to certificates and one reason could be that /etc/courier/dhparams.pem were not generated correctly. 
DH params could be regenerated by `mkdhparams` command.

Answer (score 0):

The command you used to check courier only works with servers that immediately propose to switch to TLS:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993
```

To test a mail service properly, when the mail service uses `STARTTLS` to switch to using TLS, then you need to add an option like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993 -starttls imap
```

I have no clue about the status of the service in 14.04, but I used it in 18.04 and I could setup the TLS1 protocol and it would work.

Now with that last command, you will see exactly what TLS is supported. Since you mentioned `courier`, I tried all sorts of setups and I was not able to make it work with TLSv1.2. It seems to be limited to TLSv1. If that's what you're looking to get, then you'll want to switch to another server such as dovecot which is [99% compatible](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Migration/Courier).